# How to manipulate multidimensional tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of the shape `[?,128,128,128,5]`.This represents a 3D image with 5 possible classes.

I would like to add the sub-tensors `[?,:,:,:,2]` and `[?,:,:,:,3]` inside of `[?,:,:,:,4]` which at the moment are all zeros.

Then I would like to set these previous sub-tensors `[?,:,:,:,2]` and `[?,:,:,:,3]` to zeros. How can I go about this ?

Thank you for you help !

Comment: Can you post any code that you have already tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 128, 5])
s = tf.shape(img)
img2 = tf.concat([img[..., :2],
                  tf.zeros([s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], 2], img.dtype),
                  tf.reduce_sum(img[..., 2:], axis=-1, keepdims=True)], axis=-1)
```

EDIT: As per the comments, if what you want is to keep the first and last indices of the last axis untouched, aggregate the second and third indices into the fourth index and replace the second and third indices with zeros, then you would do something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 128, 5])
z = tf.expand_dims(tf.zeros(tf.shape(img)[:-1], img.dtype), axis=-1)
img2 = tf.concat([img[..., :1],  # New 1st index is the same as before
                  z,  # New 2nd index is zeros
                  z,  # New 3rd index is zeros
                  # New 4th index is sum of 2nd, 3rd and 4th indices
                  tf.reduce_sum(img[..., 1:4], axis=-1, keepdims=True)],
                  # New last index is the same as before
                  img[..., -1:]], axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'm not exactly sure, I would like dimensions 1 and 5 to be unchanged. Dimension 4 should be the sum of dimension 2 and 3, and then dimensions 2 and 3 should be changed to zeros. Sorry if I wasn't very clear !

Comment: Note that indices are zero-based in Python, so there is no dimension 5 in this case (in the last axis you have indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4). Are you using one-based indices in your explanation? In any case, when you say "Dimension 4 should be the sum of dimension 2 and 3", does that mean that dimension 4 is discarded, or is it added along with 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes my bad. I'm new to Tensorflow, I think your answer suits my needs, so thanks a lot !

Comment: @gypaetebarbu I have edited the answer, since I think I may have misunderstood you in my first attempt.

Comment: @gypaetebarbu Well you would switch it to `img[..., 2]` since `2` is actually the third index (remember indices start at zero, so first is `0`, second `1`, etc.).

Comment: Then, using your slice notation shouldn't I use `tf.reduce_sum(img[..., 1:-1], axis=-1, keepdims=True)]` instead of `tf.reduce_sum(img[...,2:-1], axis=-1, keepdims=True)]` if I want to sum from the 2nd index?

Comment: @gypaetebarbu You're right, good catch, thanks! You can do `img[..., 1:4]` to aggregate indices `1`, `2`, and `3` (so second, third and fourth) or `img[..., 1:3]` to just aggregate `1` and `2` (second and third).